# Passing an jQuery element cache to a method for modification

Tags: javascript, reference, jquery, event-binding

**Problem Fiddle:**

**[Click To View](http://jsfiddle.net/dskmG/)** (Attempt #1, using Delegated Events)

**[Click To View](http://jsfiddle.net/gaK9H/2/)** (Attempt #2, brute force approach as below)

**[Click To View](http://jsfiddle.net/hZR6T/1/)** (Attempt #3, refactored, has problem I am trying to solve)

On a project I'm working with, I'm exploring a rather dynamic form.  In addition to some static elements, there are various interactive elements, which can be cloned from a hidden 'template' markup set and added at various points in the business process.

Because of the dynamic nature, my tried-and-true method of setting up a jQuery element cache and event handlers on-load, then letting the user do whatever isn't working out, because of this dynamic nature; I was finding that my dynamically-added elements had no click events.

To solve this problem, I manually set up a rebind method for each scripted element in question.  The rebind process involves A) re-acquiring the set of elements for a given descriptive selector, B) dropping any existing events on that cache, as those events apply to an incomplete element set, and C) calling a bind method to apply the new events to the entire set.

The brute-force, working way that I got, had this going on:

```
var $elementCache = $('.some-class');

function rebindSomeLink() {
    // Re-acquire the element cache...
    $elementCache = $('.some-class');

    // Drop all existing events on the cache...
    $elementCache.unbind();

    // Call a bind function to establish new events.
    bindSomeLink();
}

function bindSomeLink() {
    $elementCache.click(function (e) {
        // ...Behavior...
    });
}

// There are four other links with a similar rebind/bind function relationship set up.
```

Naturally, I seized on the rebind being repeated so often with nearly the exact same code - ripe for a refactor.  We have a common library namespace, where I added a `rebindEvents` function...

```
var MyCommon = function () {
    var pub = {};

    pub.rebindEvents = function($elementCache, selector, bindFunction) {
        $elementCache = $(selector);
        $elementCache.unbind();
        bindFunction();
    };

    return pub;
}();
```

Upon trying to call that, and run the site, I immediately stubbed my toe on an `UncaughtTypeError: method click cannot be called on object undefined.`

As it turns out, it seems when I call the following:

```
MyCommon.rebindEvents($elementCache, '.some-class', bindSomeLink);
```

The `$elementCache` is not being passed to the `rebindEvents` method; when I step to it in my debugger, $elementCache inside of `rebindEvents` is `undefined`.

Some handy StackOverflow research revealed to me that JavaScript **does not** have referential-passing, at least in the C/C++/C# sense that I am familiar with, which leads me to my two **Questions**:

A) Is it even possible for me to refactor this rebind functionality with a cache reference pass of some sort?

B) If it's possible for me to refactor my rebind function to my common namespace, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Just use delegated events. There is no need for complex code to rebind an event at a given point in the logic of your code. Apply the event handler to a static element which is always present.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Geoff set me straight with this; I didn't quite understand your original suggestion at the time; now, it makes perfect sense.  I deleted my other comments, as it seems the answer to questions A) and B) is A) no, and B) delegated events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery On to bind events at an element high-up in the DOM that is always present.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

This is the simplest way to handle event binding to dynamically created elements.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHBxv/) that shows an example.

```
$('#temp').on('click', 'button', function(){
   alert('clicked'); 
});

$('#temp').append('<button>OK</button>');
```

The event is bound to a div, which later has a button dynamically added.  Because the button has no click event, the event "bubbles" up the DOM tree to its parent element which does have a click event for a button, so it handles it and the event "bubbles" no further.

Comment: I don't quite understand, though I think I see what you might be getting at: are you saying, that if I bind an event handler at load-time, to my template that I am copying, that that event should carry over to the copied DOM elements?

Comment: Exactly. This is what a delegated event is.

Comment: @Geoff (and, by extension Rory) - I tried it, in the context of the problem I am working with, and it did not work.  I have attached a fiddle to the top of my question with a more complete view of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AndrewGray - Here is a modification of your first example http://jsfiddle.net/SuBA3/3/  I added a container to hold the cloned elements and then bound the events to the container.